# Python thread safe asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to run my sync functions using asyncio.run_in_executor

My coroutines shares data and update data. The run in executor starts threads. Do I need to make my objects thread and asyncio safe?

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class shared:
  #complex object

def func(a, b):
    # blocking calls
    return a + b

async def main(loop):
  
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, "Hello,", " world!")
    UpdateSharedObject(result) 

Start main as 5 tasks using create_task
```

Comment: Is are the `func` calls using a common instance of `shared`?

Comment: Also, this is unrelated to your question, but I just want to make sure you're aware that using a thread pool will not let you run purely computation tasks in parallel because of the global interpreter lock. Python threads are pretty much only useful for io bound code.

Comment: Yes. They both share same resource. The blocking call is io bound in nature.

Comment: Do you want to access those shared objects from your blocking function?

Comment: Yes.. In both async and sync

Comment: Ideally the blocking function would only do the blocking work and would return the result without changing the objects it received. In that case all modifications would be done in asyncio and you wouldn't need any additional locks. From your question it's impossible to tell what your actual code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing (and especially making changes) to the same resource from different threads. Then I highly recommend using [synchronization primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects). Because Python does not provide this thread-safety in all cases. Many Python operations are atomic, but not all. Actually, single opcodes are thread-safe.

Examples of thread-safe operations:

```
L.append(x)
L1.extend(L2)
x = L[i]
x = L.pop()
```

These are not:

```
i = i+1
L.append(L[-1])
L[i] = L[j]
D[x] = D[x] + 1
```

More info here: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe

As for `asyncio`, I agree with the @user4815162342 in the comments and advise you to redesign the program so that the functions executed in the threads are [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) and do not change shared objects. Because the use of thread synchronization, together with cooperative multitasking (`asyncio`), can greatly complicate the code and lead to subtle bugs.